# Sorting a collection of related items in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List which contains a data of type class A

```
Class A
{
int Year
int CountryID
string City
decimal SalesAmount
}
```

My requirement is to bind this list to a grid which displays items by grouping year and country and sort by salesamount desc

I achieved my half requirement by reading the values by ordering Year and CountryID, but facing issues while applying sorting

Here is the approach i used to group them.
In code behind i am reading the values by ordering on Year and CountryId and in aspx page i am adjusting rowspan to display them as grouped

```
from t in listA
order by t.Year,t.CountryID
```

So, is there a way by which i can sort this collection on salesamount by considering the conditions of same year and same country or my approach is wrong?

Adding more information to the post:

```
     List<A> list = new List<A>() 
{
    new A() { Year = 2001, CountryID = 10,State="A", SalesAmount = 322 },
    new A() { Year = 2011, CountryID = 1,State="A", SalesAmount = 23 },
    new A() { Year = 1983, CountryID = 12,State="A", SalesAmount = 6 },
    new A() { Year = 2011, CountryID = 1,State="B", SalesAmount = 211 },
    new A() { Year = 2011, CountryID = 1,State="C", SalesAmount = 32 },
    new A() { Year = 2001, CountryID = 10,State="B", SalesAmount = 65 },
    new A() { Year = 1983, CountryID = 12,State="C", SalesAmount = 22 },
    new A() { Year = 2001, CountryID = 10,State="C", SalesAmount = 1 },
};
```

Now i need to display this data on grid
[image: Data on Grid]

Comment: You need to provide more information about how you group and sort.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo: Edited the problem statement :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but I guess you want to use the `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()` [`IEnumerable<T>` extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx).

Something like:

```
List<A> list = new List<A>() 
{
    new A() { Year = 2001, CountryID = 10, SalesAmount = 322 },
    new A() { Year = 2011, CountryID = 1, SalesAmount = 23 },
    new A() { Year = 1983, CountryID = 12, SalesAmount = 6 },
    new A() { Year = 2011, CountryID = 1, SalesAmount = 211 },
    new A() { Year = 2001, CountryID = 1, SalesAmount = 32 },
    new A() { Year = 2003, CountryID = 10, SalesAmount = 65 },
    new A() { Year = 2050, CountryID = 12, SalesAmount = 22 },
    new A() { Year = 1974, CountryID = 10, SalesAmount = 1 },
};

var sortedList = list
    .OrderBy(a => a.Year)
    .ThenBy(a => a.CountryID)
    .ThenBy(a => a.SalesAmount);
```

Comment: Its not giving me the actual result i expected :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As considered and based on your update, my original query would need tweaking to something like this:

```
var groupedItems =
    from i in list
    orderby i.Year
    group i by new { i.Year, i.CountryID } into g     
    select new { Key = g.Key, A = g };
```

---

Not being entirely clear exactly what you want to achieve, might I suggest this:

```
var groupedItems = 
    from i in list
    orderby i.Year, i.CountryID
    group i by i.SalesAmount into g         
    select new { SalesAmount = g.Key, A = g };
```

So, for a collection like this:

```
List<A> list = new List<A>() 
{
    new A() { Year = 2001, CountryID = 10, SalesAmount = 322 },
    new A() { Year = 2011, CountryID = 1, SalesAmount = 23 },
    new A() { Year = 1983, CountryID = 12, SalesAmount = 6 },
    new A() { Year = 2011, CountryID = 1, SalesAmount = 322 },
    new A() { Year = 2001, CountryID = 1, SalesAmount = 322 },
    new A() { Year = 2003, CountryID = 10, SalesAmount = 6 },
    new A() { Year = 2050, CountryID = 12, SalesAmount = 23 },
    new A() { Year = 1974, CountryID = 10, SalesAmount = 23 },
};
```

We can represent the result as the following:

```
Group1 (23)
  - A { 1974, 10, 23 }
  - A { 2011, 1, 23 }
  - A { 2050, 12, 23 }

Group2 (6)
  - A { 1983, 12, 6 }
  - A { 2003, 10, 6 }

Group3 (322)
  - A { 2001, 1, 322 }
  - A { 2001, 10, 322 }
  - A { 2011, 1, 322 }
```

I supposed you might then want to order the groups, which would be trivial.

Comment: hmm.. but still the answer was not solving my problem :(